# Undefined array key in Form Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, async-await, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image using form Data. But the name of the form field server expects is not recognizable.

## Warning: Undefined array key "photo"

Below is my code:

**index.html**

```
html>
<head>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="uploadImage()">upload an Image</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
async function uploadImage(){
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('photo',{
        name: 'timg', 
        type: 'image/jpeg', 
        uri: 'C:\Users\mea\Downloads\testimg.jpeg'
    })
    return await fetch('upload_image.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
}
```

**upload_image.php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $target_dir = "../../images";
    $target_file = $target_dir .'/'.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo json_encode (
        array('message' => 'Image uploaded Successfully'));}
    else{
        echo json_encode (
        array('message' => 'Upload failed!'));
    }
?>
```

I have tried all the available solutions but can not yet find the cause.

Comment: I'm fairly certain browser security policies will not permit you to specify the path to a local file in the `uri` parameter. Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @rickdenhaan there are no errors but only warnings like `Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0` I have tried replacing it with undefined to let the browser decide.

Comment: If you add print_r($_POST); to your upload_image.php file and inspect, I believe you'll see you've only sent an object with some info to this page, not a file.  I think you need to set up a form with an HTML input of type file to collect the file and post that OR, in upload_Image.php you need to take the URI and do file_get_contents.

Comment: @ChadPhillips At this point print_r($_POST); returns me nothing but `setArray ( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in approach. $_FILE will return empty since this is not an file upload from HTML form. I have created a better approach that you may try.

> index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="uploadImage()">Upload</button>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    async function uploadImage(){
        image_url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image_url", image_url);
        formData.append("image_name", "googlelogo");
        formData.append("image_type", "png");
        
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/upload_image.php");
        request.send(formData);
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> upload_image.php

```
<?php
try {
    $image_url = $_POST['image_url'];
    $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];
    $image_type = $_POST['image_type'];

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . $image_name . "." . $image_type;
    // save image to uploads folder
    file_put_contents($target_file, file_get_contents($image_url));
    echo "Image uploaded successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

And always use try catch statement to find the error. The try statement allows you to define a block of code to be tested for errors while it is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

If the code snippet provided is complete then I can see multiple issues with this.

The issue `Undefined array key "photo"` suggests that PHP did not recognise the 'photo' key.

To fix this there are a few adjustments in both (HTML and JS)

**HTML: Add an input field to get the image**

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<button onclick="uploadImage()">Upload an Image</button>
```

**JS: Append image data to FormData**

```js
async function uploadImage() {
    const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    const file = input.files[0];

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', file);

    return await fetch('upload_image.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        //headers: {
            //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        //}
    });
}
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to upload a local file by specifying its location. But this is extremely unsafe and browsers do not allow you to do this. Imagine the case when you visit a site and that site, programmatically, without your consent would want some of your local files to be uploaded to their server. You would most certainly not be okay with it.

So, instead of you programmatically specifying what file you want to fetch from the user, you will need to let the user choose to upload a file, like:

```
<form action="some/action" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <submit>Click me</submit>
</form>
```